# Accessing each element in ArrayDeque

Tags: java, compiler-errors, iterator, arraydeque

Is it possible to access the element stored in ArrayDeque in each iteration ? Since ArrayDeque doesn't have the get method, its difficult for me to access each element. In the following example I have an integer arraydeque and i'm trying to retrieve the elements using an iterator and i want to check if the value is 2. If so i want to remove it from the ArrayDeque, but it gives me error.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayDequeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    ArrayDeque<Integer> a = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    a.add(4);
    a.add(2);
    System.out.println("Elements added !!");

    Iterator i = a.iterator();
    System.out.println("\nRemoving the element whose value is 2");
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        if(i==2) // please suggest as to how i can compare
        {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can make use of lambda expression and can get this removal operation done in just one line.

```
 a.removeIf(e -> e == 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help YCF_L and thanks Punit Mittal ! I tried removeIf and it worked easily !

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a call to `next()` to advance the iterator and retrieve the current value:

```
Iterator<Integer> i = a.iterator();
while (i.hasNext())
{
    if (i.next() == 2) // Here!
    {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Note, BTW, that `ArrayDeque` is a `Collection`, so you could use the much more elegant [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
a.removeIf(v -> v == 2);
```

Comment: Also, iterator variable i should be of type Iterator<Integer> in order for comparison to work.

Comment: Will removeIf iterate through the collection?

Comment: @PavelMolchanov yes

Comment: Thanks for the help Mureinik and Adi ! I tried the next() method and it worked for me. And i tried comparing the objects using equals() method. Worked !!! Thanks !

Comment: `if((i.next()).equals(2))  
   {  
     i.remove();  
   }`